# hotmail & webmail unable to receive transactional email? why? my site is on magento 1.8.3.8

Tags: email, magento-1.9.3.8

During my customers signup an account on my website magento 1.9.3.8 if its an gmail account the person receives confirmation if its a hotmail or a webmail he is unable to receive any email?

my site is - semipreciousking.com

Comment: I have faced problems with microsoft e-mails in the past, in my case, transactional e-mails for microsoft e-mails takes more time to appear on inbox tha gmail for example, maybe the server takes more time to process its queue.

Comment: But i have not received at all been 2 days

Comment: Please check the mail logs on the server. If you are using the server with cPanel, you can easily find it there.
I think some hosts are being blacklisted from the server.

Answer (score 1):

There are some challenges when sending to Microsoft mailboxes.
https://elasticemail.com/blog/sending-to-microsoft-is-more-challenging-recently/ - check out the guides in this article.

You need to check your IP, domain for blacklists and make sure that your domain is properly verified to send those emails.